# ExtJs 4.1 minWidth and align "stretch" not working togather

Tags: javascript, css, extjs, sencha-touch, extjs4.1

I have this code(https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/r38):

```
Ext.onReady(function () {
        Ext.create("Ext.panel.Panel", {
            renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
            height: 200,
            autoScroll: true,
            items: [{
                layout: {
                    type: "vbox",
                    align: "stretch"
                },
                minWidth: 400
            }
            ],
            layout: {
                type: "vbox",
                align: "stretch"
            }
        });
    });
```

I need to show horizontal scrollbar if size of window will be less than  minWidth, i.e. 400px. But it not showing. I'm looking for generic solution, as far as in real project I have more complex tree structure.

Comment: Do you mean 'minHeight'? Vertical scrollbar should show up if height changes, not width. Height stays the same if only width changes.

Comment: i mean horisontal scrollbar. thanks,

Answer (score 0):

try to add:

```
 flex: 1
```

inside your 'items'

also add:

```
cls: 'my-panel'
```

for your panel

then try to use media-query in you sass/css styles:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 400px){
   .my-panel{
       overflow-x: scroll;
   }
}
```

Comment: Interesting idea, but main problem: originally my `main` component is not a window - it is `center` panel in border layout, and I have there also 'west' panel, wich can be collapsed. So I cannot depend on screen width. :(

Comment: would be nice if you have the full layout in the fiddle, add a panel title would make it a bit more visual, even some dummy items would be helpful too. i believe you will need to handle a resize event to get this fully working, and yes, as you already pointed out, stretch will take the whatever available space and ignore the autoScroll config.